# How to insert input, text area and image upload into database

Tags: php

Hye, currently I follow some tutorial in the video, but I don't know how my data doesn't upload pic into a database.

This is happening in my database when I put some data in a form and my pic still doesn't upload

This is code in PHP

```
<?php
$sqlservername = "127.0.0.1";
$sqlusername = "root";
$sqlpassword = "";
$sqldbname ="test";

$conn = new mysqli($sqlservername, $sqlusername, $sqlpassword, $sqldbname);

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection fail");
}

session_start();



if(isset($_POST['li_submit'])){
    $_SESSION['li_username'] = $_POST['username'];

    $li_username = $_SESSION['li_username'];    
}   

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
$id = $username = $password = $location = $description = "";

if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $id = uniqid($prefix='u_');

    $username = $_POST['username'];

}

if(isset($_POST['password'])){
    $password = $_POST['password'];}

if(isset($_POST['location'])){
    $location = $_POST['location'];
}

if(isset($_POST['description']))
{
    $description = $_POST['description'];
}

if(isset($_FILES['profile_pic'])){
    $target_dir = "IMG_UPLOAD/";

    $target_file = basename($_FILES['profile_pic']["name"]);

    $file_type = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    $target_path = $target_dir . uniqid($prefix='img.'). "." .$file_type;

    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILE['profile_pic']['tmp_name'], $target_path)){
        $target_path = "";
    }

    echo $target_path;

}   

$sql_insert = $conn->prepare("insert into user_info(id, username, password, 

location, description, image_path) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$sql_insert->bind_param("ssssss", $id, $username, $password, $location, 

$description, $target_path);

$sql_insert->execute();

$sql_insert->close();

}

$conn->close();

?>
```

and this code in HTML incase you want to see it

```
<body>
<h1>Profile</h1>

<form method='post' enctype=''multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='name' name='username' placeholder='Username'/>
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'/>
    <input type='test' name='location'placeholder='Location'/>
    <textarea name='description'>Enter about yourself</textarea>
    <input type='file' name='profile_pic'/>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='save'/>




</form>

</body>
```

i expect when i press save button, all my data that i had put will save a to a database including picture based on screenshot. Please help me, im still newbie in PHP

Comment: Is that a typo in the enctype of the <form> tag: `<form method='post' enctype=''multipart/form-data'>`? You have two quotes before the `multipart` (and probably that is  why the file is not submitted).

Comment: ok now all my data that being insert in form succed upload into database, coz all my declaration is $username, hahahaha. Silly me, and now i need to find a way how to upload picture into database

Answer (score 0):

you have another typo in the following line. It will be $_FILES not $_FILE.

```
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILE['profile_pic']['tmp_name'], $target_path)){
```

for inserting data into the database, use the following code:

```
$sql_insert = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into user_info (username, password, location, description, image_path) values ('$username', '$password', '$location', '$description', '$target_path')");
```

Set id as primary key and auto increment.

Also make sure you have created a folder named "IMG_UPLOAD" in the directory containing your php file.

Comment: so mean, that ID will generate automatic without any statement in my code?

Comment: yeah no need to set id as primary key. Your way of inserting id into database is alright :)  @MrHaikal